Using texlive otf fonts in pdflatex
I'm trying to use a font to add an example of hand-written fields in a form.
QT Florencia seems appropriate.  I have texlive-fonts-extra installed on my debian machine, and the OTF is there:
$ dpkg -l texlive* | grep ^ii
ii  texlive                       2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: A decent selection of the TeX Live packages
ii  texlive-base                  2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: Essential programs and files
ii  texlive-binaries              2020.20200327.54578-7+deb11u2 amd64        Binaries for TeX Live
ii  texlive-fonts-extra           2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: Additional fonts
ii  texlive-fonts-extra-links     2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: Setup of fonts for TeX Live and search via kpathsea
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended     2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: Recommended fonts
ii  texlive-latex-base            2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: LaTeX fundamental packages
ii  texlive-latex-base-doc        2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-base
ii  texlive-latex-extra           2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
ii  texlive-latex-extra-doc       2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-extra
ii  texlive-latex-recommended     2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
ii  texlive-pictures              2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams
ii  texlive-plain-generic         2020.20210202-3               all          TeX Live: Plain (La)TeX packages

$ dpkg -L texlive-fonts-extra | grep QTFlorencia
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/qualitype/QTFlorencia.otf

I know package fontspec has some convenient tools where I can:
\newfontface{\florencia}{QTFlorencia.otf}
...
{\florencia My Name Here}

But fontspec only works with xelatex or lualatex.  Is there a solution for pdflatex?

pdflatex is restricted to  256-character fonts so can not really use OTF fonts at all, there are tools to make multiple subset 8-bit encoded fonts for pdftex from an OTF, but why require pdftex?, it is almost certainly easier and longer term more maintanable to use lualatex and directly use the Unicode OTF font.

I am considering pushing a migration to xelatex or lualatex on my organization, but things are slow, scripts will need to be re-written, and people don't like change.  But I do think that's the way to go long-term.

if you are migrating migrate to luatex

In my at-home projects, I've found lua flavours work well too.

that was the official latex project advice, not just a personal comment see for example https://www.texdev.net/2024/11/05/engine-news-from-the-latex-project

Good reference, thanks

There is an answer regarding a conversion with autoinst or otftotfm, but neither of those binaries are deployed in the texlive-binaries package, and it took me a long time to figure out the rest.
To install otftotfm:
sudo apt install lcdf-typetools

From here, man otftotfm is very helpful.  Next, use it on the target OTF to generate the TFM that will work with pdflatex
sudo otftotfm \
    -a -e texnansx \
    /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/qualitype/QTFlorencia.otf \
    florencia

A few notes on what's going on:

sudo is necessary because it's going to install the generated files into your /usr/share/texlive-texmf directory so latex can find it.  You'll need write permissions.
-a/--automatic tells otftotfm to install everything.  Otherwise it'll generate local files only.  I would normally love local files (so collaborators can use the same fonts without manual effort), but I couldn't get the local versions to work.
-e texnansx supplies an encoding.  Without it, things don't seem to work.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/qualitype/QTFlorencia.otf is the location of the otf
florencia is the name you want to give the font.  The name is arbitrary, but you'll use it to refer to your font in your tex.

To use the font, add this to your pre-amble.  In my case, I choose \handwritten, so it's clear what I'm doing in the document.
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc} % Load the texnansx encoding
\font\handwritten=florencia at 10pt

Then, when you're setting a word or section to use this font in your document:
{\handwritten My Name Here}


I wrote this as an answer because I've spent a lot of hours on it.  I'm still not satisfied with the -a argument to otftotfm because I need to give these installation instructions to anyone else who wants to compile this document.  I'd prefer local *.enc *.tfm if possible.

I don't understand your claim that autoinst and the tools are not in texlive. It is in my bin folder and normally using autoinst works fine.

It turns out otftofm is in the lcdf-typetools package in Debian.  dpkg -L texlive-binaries  shows 151 programs in /usr/bin, but otftofm isn't one of them. I couldn't find autoinst unless it's part of package libextutils-autoinstall-perl.

Both programs are in the upstream texlive if you install it from TUG. the debian packaged texlive probably drops them if the same binaries are in their own debian package.

It would be better to declare the font with latex declarations than the \font primitive, so that it obeyed at least size commands like \small even if the font is only available in one style

-e texnansx supplies an encoding.  that would be Y&Y's texandasnsi encoding known as LY1 in laTeX so you would need \usepackage[LY1]{fontenc} to use this font otherwise any non-ascii characters are likely to get the wrong character as LY1 only matches the standard T1 encoding in the ascii range.

Re \font:  it worked, but I'm happy for suggestions.  I kept trying to find info about better latex declarations, but everything I find seems to be provided by fontspec which isn't supported by pdflatex.  That's probably more evidence that I should up the priority on getting us away from pdflatex.

\font does not work it just accidentally gives the right characters for those characters that are in the same position in the encoding latex is using and in LY1 which is the encoding you used for the font. So if you are writing in English and have no accents you get away with it If you are writing in a west european language it will fail sometimes, and if you are writing in an east european language with latin2 accents it will fail almost always

If all else fails: Create a new 8-bit font using FontForge font editor, and copy the characters you need into it, with the OT1 or whatever encoding. This is brute force, not best. But it works. When you say "handwritten font" I assume that you only need alphanumeric characters, not math capability.
